# Drop function is not working with data frame of python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df.drop(['column_name'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

gives

```
"Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/home/sourav/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3697
    errors=errors)
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy"
```

Comment: drop command shouldn't be causing the SettingWithCopyWarning. Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: This drop command works. You are doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your `df` is a (not-properly-done) copy of another `pandas.DataFrame`.

Following reproduces the `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

```
import pandas as pd

raw = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2], "b": [2,3], "c": [3,4]})
df = raw[["a", "b"]]
df.drop(["a"], 1, inplace = True)
```

> SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>     errors=errors)

When you make another `pandas.DataFrame` from an existing one, never do direct assignment like `df = raw[["a", "b"]]`. Instead, use `pandas.DataFrame.copy()`.

```
raw = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2], "b": [2,3], "c": [3,4]})
df = raw[["a", "b"]].copy()
df.drop(["a"], 1, inplace = True)
```

Now the warning disappears, as `df` is a new object created, and thus according to [the official document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

> Modifications to the data or indices of the copy will not be reflected in the original object

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common warning when working with pandas library, but according to [dataquest](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/), I can give you some of the most important tips in short.

- The first thing to understand is that SettingWithCopyWarning is a
  warning, and not an error.
- It can be tempting to ignore the warning if your code still works as
  expected. This is bad practice and SettingWithCopyWarning should
  never be ignored. Take some time to understand why you are getting
  the warning before taking action.

I refer you to the website itself for more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

The `drop` usually doesn't create a `SettingWithCopyWarning`. 
But there's a chance that the `dataframe` you're getting is generated dynamically through slicing.

In that case try this:

```
data_new = data.drop('columnname', axis= 1)
```